# How its possible to add players order through Classes

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, prototype

I started to study ES6, classes and inheritance, I want to make an easy game, I dont know how to correctly implement the change of the player's movement? Here is my code, the player has two moves, if they tries to do more, program will get an error. I dont know how to mark the end of the players turn?

```
class State{
    constructor(){
        this.gameStep = 0;
        this.playerName = '';

    }

    checkState(){
        console.log(this.playerName);
    }
}


class Player extends State{
    constructor(name){
        super();
        this.playerStep = 0;
        this.playerName = name;
    }

    addOne(){
        this.playerStep++;
        if(this.playerStep > 2){
            console.log(new Error('More then 2 times, now another player turn'));
            return;
        }
        console.log(this.playerStep);
    }
}

Player.playerStep = 2;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well how does your game make a player have a turn in the first place? And as controlling whose turn it is, is more of a game controller logic it wouldn't go in the player controller logic.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, thanks for reply! Can you give me an advice? Where I can read about the switching turns between two players? Or maybe you can tell, I dont need a complete code, I just want to know which direction to move.